# EF5 SaveChanges()

Tags: entity-framework-5

i'm new in Entity Framwork, and I have a problem with `SaveChanges()` method:
I have only a overload with no parameters; I don't have `SaveChanges(Option)` or  `SaveChanges(Bool)`. Why?

Comment: The documentation only shows `SaveChanges()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: yes, I know..but I've found a lot of discussions in which they suggest to use SaveChanges(Option) or SaveChanges(Bool). What kind of library they use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure the `SaveChanges(bool)` was an old ObjectContext method.

I imagine it is now deprecated in favour of `SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 0):

`SaveChanges()` works on state modifications that are stored automatically when you do CRUD operations. That's the reason why nothing more is needed.

Be sure to call `SaveChanges()` at the good moment in your code, to ensure that relational constraints are good (for foreign key consistency).